# Why can I no longer access my websites, via PuTTY and FileZilla?

Tags: router, ssh, ftp, putty, filezilla

For many years, I have been using `PuTTY` and `Filezilla` when managing my websites.  I have used these programs, with no problems up until now.

For the past 5 days, I have been away where I have not been using `PuTTY` or `FileZilla`.  Additionally, the Router has not been used neither.

Upon returning, I tried accessing my websites via `FileZilla` and `PuTTY`, where I came across the following issues:

**PuTTY:**

[image]

**FileZilla:**

[image]

After some initial online reading, some suggested that there could be some issue with the Ports.  I have spoken with the Internet Service Provider, who have stated that they do not block any Ports and that no changes had been performed within the past few days.

I have no problems accessing the rest of the web and can use PuTTY and FileZilla when operating from a different IP address.

Other explored avenues, include:

- Rebooting the Router, via the ISP's Router Control Panel;
- Switching the Router off then back on again after 30 seconds;
- Using a different device, on the same Router.

I have never come across this before.  Anyone else aware of any other Troubleshooting options?

Comment: Can you ping or tracert successfully to those sites?

Comment: Could you add please to the question details, - where web site(s) are hosted? Are websites out of your premises (home/work) or they lives outside (shared hosting/VPS, dedicated servers)

Comment: Did you also reboot the computer itself?

Comment: Thanks for all your questions and time.  I am not really sure what is meant by 'tracert'.  The websites are hosted on a VPS and I have rebooted by computer to no success.  That said, I can use the relevant programmes/access my server, when either using a different Router or working from a different IP address.  Leading me to believe there is an issue with the Router.

Comment: Check your public IP when connected to a working router and when connected to the non-working router. (Google whatsmyip) Depending on your ISP you might be getting the same IP all the time for each specific device, but a different IP between the two. This would mean the one IP address has been blocked either by the hosting provider or by the firewall on the server. Could be CSF firewall blacklisted your IP or something. Or fail2ban, etc.

Comment: @Appleoddity:  All of a sudden, I cannot seem to connect, no matter what Router I use. The problem is, I have set the VPS to only accept login efforts from a particular IP address. My IP address has now changed and the only way I can change the allowed IP address is via software such as PuTTY. But it will not allow me to login. I have spoken with my ISP who have stated that my Port has closed and I need to reopen it via Port Forwarding. I have tried this but still it states that the Port is closed.  I have rebooted the Router but to no success.  How can I check if fail2ban is blocking my IP?

Comment: ...if you have it set to only accept login attempts from a specific IP, there's your problem.  Spoof it to get in.

Comment: Thanks for the directive @Appleoddity (and others).  Turns out it was the 'fail2ban' resource.  I have limited Control Panel Access to a single IP Address, however was able to override this via PuTTY in the event of the IP Address changing.  It was since having 'fail2ban' installed, which was preventing me override the IP Addresses via PuTTY and accessing my Web Files via FileZilla.  Thanks all, for your time and advice.